# Find how many times each character appears in a linked list of strings

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I have to find out how many times each character repeats in a linked list of strings. The string is stored and read from a file. I have to print out the result in 2 ways: alphabetic order and in growing order.

I have tried to write a function which will count the number of times a given char repeats, but it crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct list {
    char *string;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list LIST;

int count(struct list* head, char search) // funct to calculate how many 
                                          //times 1 string appears
{
    struct list* current = head;
    int count=0;
    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        if(current->string == search)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[128];
    LIST *current, *head;

    head = current = NULL;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
        node->string = strdup(line);
        node->next =NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
            current = head = node;
        } else {
            current = current->next = node;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //test print
    for(current = head; current ; current=current->next){
        printf("%s", current->string);
    }

    count(head, "a");

    return 0;
}
```

The test.txt file contains:

```
Astazi nu este maine
```

Comment: I've added a line after the count++ in the `int count` function which is `current = current->next;` but when printing it out, it prints me 0, although it should be 2

Comment: Your example relies on a test.txt which you did not share with us.  I suggest you simplify your example and hard-code the test data to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @AllanWind just edited the description, I've put the data from test.txt in it

Comment: See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, improve your code to get no warnings, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable.

Comment: Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source programs like [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: The problem here is that your code **emits several warnings** from the compiler but you don't mention it in the question. You should **google** those warning messages and read the relevant Stack Overflow questions **even before** posting your own question.

Comment: If there is a single node with string = "aa" should count() return 0, 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `if(current->string == search)` compares a pointer (char *) to a char.  If current->string is a single character you can use `if(*current->string == search)`.  If string contains multiple characters you have to tell me what the `count()` of the string "aa" is with search of 'a'.  The other major problem is that your `while` loop in `count()` doesn't walk the linked list so it would result in an infinite loop.

```
int count(struct list *head, char search) {
    int count = 0;
    for(struct list* current = head; current; current = current->next) {
        for(int i = 0; current->string[i]; i++)
            if(current->string[i] == search) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: The question actually says that the problem is in the function that is supposed to count the number of occurrences for a single character in a string, which you do not address at all.

Comment: Fair enough, I was still writing up my answer.

Comment: @AllanWind thank you for your help. Although, when I'm trying to print it, it still gives me 0, maybe I use the wrong prinf: `printf("\n%d", count(head, "a"));`

Comment: count takes a char so you need to call it as `count(head, 'a')` for example: `printf("%d\n", count(head, 'a'));` which returns 2 when test.txt contains two lines with "a"s.

Comment: @AllanWind no jokes, it still gives me 0

Comment: @Vlad, I see, your input now.  See updated answer.